# Form Validation exercise

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I've been working on this project for over a week and cannot figure out why my form skips the validation process. The form is supposed to be emailed if everything validates with no errors. When I click the submit button, it emails whatever I have entered in the fields without validating the information.

All my code is posted at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbrinegar/pcj6b0tg/7/)

```
    function formValidation() {

  //array to collect error messages
  var error = [];

  //regEx variables
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  var letnum = /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/;
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;

  //validate First Name field
  var fn = document.getElementById("fName");
  if (fn.value == "" || fn.value === "Your First Name") {
    error.push("First name is required.");
  } else if (!fn.value.match(letters)) {
    error.push("First name can only include letters of the alphabet.");
  }

  //validate Last Name field
  var ln = document.getElementByID("lName");
  if (ln.value == "" || ln.value === "Your Last Name") {
    error.push("Last name is required.");
  } else if (!fn.value.match(letters)) {
    error.push("Last name can only include letters of the alphabet.");
  }

  //validate Address field
  var st = document.getElementById("street");
  if (st.value == "") {
    error.push("Address is required.");
  } else if (st.value.match(letnum)) {
    error.push("Address can only use letters of the alphabet and numbers.");
  }

  //validate City field
  var c = document.getElementById("city");
  if (c.value == "") {
    error.push("City is required.");
  } else if (c.value.match(letters)) {
    error.push("City can only use letters of the alphabet.");
  }

  //validate State is selected
  var s = document.getElementById("states");
  var stateChoice = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;
  if (stateChoice == "default") {
    error.push("Please select a State.");
  }

  //validate Zip Code field
  var zc = document.getElementById("zip");
  if (zc.value == "") {
    error.push("Zip Code is required.");
  } else if (!zc.value.match(numbers)) {
    error.push("Zip Code can only use numbers.");
  } else if (zc.value.length < 5 || zc.value.length > 5) {
    error.push("Please enter a valid US Zip Code.");
  }

  //validate Phone field
  var a = document.getElementById("area");
  var ph = document.getElementById("phone");
  if (a.value == "" || ph.value == "") {
    error.push("Phone Number is required.");
  } else if (a.value.length < 3 || a.value.length > 3 ||
    ph.value.length < 7 || ph.value.length > 7) {
    error.push("Please enter a valid phone number.");
  }

  //validate Email field
  var e = document.getElementById("email");
  if (e.value == "") {
    error.push("Email address is required.");
  } else if (e.value.indexOf("@", 0) == -1 || e.value.indexOf("@", 0) == 64 ||
    e.value.indexOf(".", 0) == = 1 || e.value.indexOf(".", 0) == e.value.indexOf("@", 0) + 252) {
    error.push("Please enter a valid email address.");
  }

  //validate Email Confirmation field
  if (ec.value == "") {
    error.push("Please confirm your email address.");
  } else if (ec.value !== e.value) {
    error.push("Your email addresses do not match.");
  }

  //validate Meal Preference is selected
  var m = document.getElementsByName("meal");
  var formValid = false;
  var i = 0;
  while (!formValid && i < m.length) {
    if (m[i].checked) {
      formValid = true;
    }
    i++;
  }

  if (!formValid) {
    error.push("Must choose a meal preference.");
  }

  //validate at lease 2 Contact Methods are selected
  var cm = document.getElementsByName("contact");
  var count = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < cm.length; i++) {
    if (cm[i].checked) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  if (count < 2) {
    error.push("You must choose at least two contact methods.");
  }

  //validate Comments field
  var comm = document.getElementByID("comm");
  if (comm.length > 250) {
    error.push("Please limit your comments to 250 characters.");
  }

  //return false if errors occurred or true if no errors occurred
  if (error.length > 0) {
    alert("Errors occurred\n\n" + error.join("\n"));
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried to console.log the value of the input and make sure its what you expect? for example leave the first name empty and console.log(fn.value)

Comment: It's almost like the javascript file isn't being called at all. I've tried adding console.log, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: can we see how you call/include the script?

Comment: That's really odd. I found what @trincot found and it still is not working...I would say if you're in a time crunch just slap in a plugin and call it a day https://jqueryvalidation.org/ or http://parsleyjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

I see three issues:

1. The [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbrinegar/pcj6b0tg/7/) is not configured right, which explains that in the fiddle (only) the function is never executed. In the JS panel there is a menu with "Load Type". By default "On Load" is selected, but you should choose "No wrap - bottom of body". The default option wraps the function in another anonymous function, and then it is not visible any more to your HTML attributes.
2. Your code has one case where `getElementById` is spelled wrong: it has a capital "D" at the end, and this will break the code.
3. Your code references the `select` element with `document.getElementById("states");`, but that element only has a `name` attribute, not an `id`. So give that `select` element an `id="states"` attributes.

Comment: I saw all that too, but it still doesn't work. check out the fork: http://jsfiddle.net/mLvke3dq/

Comment: thats weird well I changed it I must have forgot to save it